# Boundary Detection trained for Specific Boundary through Deep Learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am currently looking for the best way to complete a project of mine. This entails a network trained to detect a particular boundary in an image. I have attached an example image below that shows such a boundary (the tree ring). In this case, of course, an edge detector would find many other edges in the image in addition to the one I want. The end goal is to detect the boundary and essentially draw an approximate line at the ring.

I am some experience with PyTorch and have implemented some simple object detection networks, but in my search for a project similar to this, all I have found is doing edge detection through deep learning, but this will detect all edges. I have thought of maybe doing the detection in steps, starting with edge detection and training a CNN on the straight edges, but that does not seem like it will be accurate.

I also thought of trying to train a CNN on images that are centered on a point on the boundary. Thus, every good result from the CNN should be essentially a point on a line, I can then just run some simple linear regression on it to draw. However, I am not sure if any of these ideas will work out. Of course, I can try them out but was hoping for some insight from the experienced.

[image: Example image of tree core. Focus on dark blue marks, they mark the ring.]

Example image of tree core. Focus on dark blue marks, they mark the ring. Ignore the lines connecting the marks, and the light blue/white marks.

Comment: You could train a CNN using classifications of all the different segments in the image (rings, dots, bark, etc.. etc..). Once trained you can use the NN to generate a segmentation mask as output, and then it should be easy to calculate what you want from the segments. https://blog.athelas.com/a-brief-history-of-cnns-in-image-segmentation-from-r-cnn-to-mask-r-cnn-34ea83205de4

Comment: So are you saying just detect everything and when I have everything, I can figure out the boundary? I am not sure how accurate that would be...

Comment: It doesn't really work like that. CNN is going to see a lot of features in your sample image. You'll have to train over a large set and NN will build a relationship between all the features and classifications. If you try to train "this has rings" it will just tell the difference between the sample images and a photo of a dog. You're trying to extract details from the image, and that sounds like segmentation. So you have to train it how to segment that image into many different parts. Once you have those parts, then you can calculate some thing from that data.

Comment: You could try to use transfer training and extend some thing like ImageNet to classify your sample images. That will reduce the amount of training needed, but I haven't done that before so I can't say how it would work exactly.

Comment: The idea I proposed in the post with the cnn would break the image into small pieces and would be trained to find images with the ring in the center. Not sure if this makes sense, let me know.